# Why does this Context.Sync not work?

Tags: excel, office-js

Why does this code snippet not write the values back to Excel unless I un-comment the range.values=range.values line?

```
$('#run').click(function() {
    invokeRun()
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.logError);
});
function invokeRun() {
    return Excel.run(function(context) {
        var range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:B3");
        range.load('values');
        return context.sync()
            .then(function() {
               range.values[1][1]=99;
               console.log(JSON.stringify(range.values));
                //range.values=range.values
                return context.sync();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array properties are special.  I have added a page on my website to describe the topic:  **[Reading and writing array properties](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/array-properties/)**.

Summarizing from there, the way that the proxy-object model works, whenever you set a property on an object, the Office.js runtime has a hook into the setter and getter, which is used to intercept the call and add the command to the queue.

Let's take an example of a regular property first.  Per the above, whenever you set something like `range.format.fill.color = "red"`, the setter for the color property intercepts the request and internally adds a command into the queue to set the range fill color to red (to be dispatched with the next `context.sync`)

On the other hand, if all you had was `var color = range.format.fill.color`
(after a `load` and a `sync`, of course), the getter would fire instead of the setter, and the color variable would get the range's current fill color.

Now, that was regular properties.  Whenever you set an *element of the array*, you are effectively accessing the array value as a getter.  From a runtime perspective, this line is no different from a slightly more verbose version:

```
var array = range.values;
array[r][c] = '-';
```

Because the getter for `range.values` returns a perfectly plain JS array object, accessing it and then setting its value does nothing to propagate it back to the original Range object.

If you want the values to get reflected back, the best thing is to get a reference to the array right after the sync (i.e., var array = range.values, just as above), then set the values on the array as needed, and then finally set it back to the object: `range.values = array`.

It means you could also modify the values array in place, and then assign the values property back to itself at the completion of the loop (`range.values = range.values`).  However, this looks awkward, as if it’s a no-op, whereas in reality it is not.  So personally, I prefer to retrieve the array at the beginning and assign it to its own variable, then do any necessary modifications, and finally set the full array back.

**UPDATE to clarify the above:**

To be very clear, the arrays returned by accessing the `.values`, `.formulas`, etc., **ARE** pure vanilla JS arrays.  That's actually the crux of the problem:  that in order for Office.js to return pure objects, it means that those pure objects can't be "spiked" with the ability to reflect changes.

For what it's worth, we actually have an upcoming feature that should be rolling out in a month or two, where we will be introducing an `object.set` syntax, as in:

```
range.set({
   values: [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
   format: {
       fill: {
           color: "purple"
       }
   }
}
```

This will make it more convenient to set multiple properties on the same object, but it might also make the array properties easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I really appreciate the explanation. However I can't help feeling that this is a bit too clever/over complicated/ a bug.<br> Personally I would much prefer having control over getting and setting rather than having to work out and learn what the JS runtime is going to do in different circumstances. Alternatively the setter should kick in whenever a proxy object is on the left hand side of an assignment (which is what you would expect if its going to be clever)

Comment: Agreed that this is unusual -- and that it's unfortunate that the developer needs to remember an extra concept here.  Sadly, I don't think there is much we can do here (though fortunately, it's only arrays that have this issue).  The proxy object model is a very useful abstraction over an asynchronous OM, but it does break down a bit here (though the alternative, of having our own "spiked" version of an array, would be even less desirable in my opinion -- hence we have what we have now).

Comment: Alternatively you could have a Set command (the opposite of Load)  that allowed parameters for better control of what gets returned back to excel. As you can tell I am still trying to get my head around how proxy objects really work! I suppose one thing that puzzles me is that it is not a vanilla array - its an object containing an array. And from a performance POV its not great to be making additional copies of potentially large data volumes.

Comment: Thanks Michael: Set looks like the answer - thats great!